# Is there a way to restrict allowed characters in a path on a Windows fileserver?

Tags: ntfs, smb, windows-server

There are many characters that Windows won't allow in a path, like `\/:*?"<>|`.

I would like to expand upon that list. I want to further restrict what characters can be used on a file-server to avoid humans making strange paths that certain applications can't handle.

Sure, we tell people not to use certain characters because it breaks XYZ but as the company grows user training becomes more difficult for such an obscure thing. It would be much nicer to just not allow it on the file-server.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're asking for something to be restricted which is required by the filesystem? `\` in this case.

Comment: worth reading: https://serverfault.com/questions/371830/add-restrictions-for-files-and-folders-naming-on-windows

Comment: @NordlysJeger, No I didn't specify which characters. That is off topic. The question is about possibility to restrict the use of any valid path character.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That question is similar. I'm not sure a file screen can be applied to paths. I read the Microsoft docs and they are not clear on that.